# Problems with jQuery and "hash"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtouch

i've got some problems using jQTouch. I have this Link

```
<a href="#site_map" class="swap">Map</a>
```

and this jQTouch initalization:

```
var jQT = new $.jQTouch({
            icon: 'jqtouch.png',
            icon4: 'jqtouch4.png',
            addGlossToIcon: false,
            startupScreen: 'jqt_startup.png',
            preloadImages: []
        });
```

Sooo... the Console (Google Chrome) says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined

Line 331, jQTouch.js...
```

Somebody any Idea?

Some aditional Informations:

Firefox Console:

```
hash is undefined 
hash = hash.replace(/^#/, ''),
jqtouch.js (Zeile 431)   
(432 out of range 4)
jquery.js (Zeile 432)
```

And Finally, Safari Console:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'hash.replace')
```

Comment: can you reformat your code, pls? Cannot see what is that 'Map' link

Comment: So is there an element with id="site_map" in your page?

Comment: Yes, it's a "hidden page" (css hidden div elem), where i want jQtouch to go to...

Comment: I am using jQuery (version 1.7.1).

Comment: You're declaring a new object `jQT` but where are you calling it from? Did you want to append it to class `swap`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what u mean with "where are you calling it from", but its in the `$(document).ready(function()` function from jQuery.. 
    
I wanted the effect of the "switch" to be a Swipe-Effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure if you're using jQTouch with jQuery, that you load the base JQT along with the JQT jQuery bridge file (odd - plugin was originally started to work with jQuery, now requires a separate add-in script to work with it instead of Zepto.js)

Also - is this error occurring on page load? Is this a static HTML page that you're using JQTouch for, or is this dynamically created using PHP, .NET, etc?

Answer (score 0):

That's because hash is on window.location.

You could just do:

`var hash = location.hash.replace(/^#/, '')`